# Implementing Session Using Handlers

Tags: c#, ajax, handler

I am Trying to implement session in one of m project.After retrieving password and verification i am sending `emailadd` to a handler Via Ajax Call. This is the code of `setsession`

```
public class setsession : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string email = (context.Request.QueryString["email"]);
        context.Session["Emailadd"] = email;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

After this i am redirecting my page to second page and at the beginning of page with a ajax call i am trying to retrieve stored Email add. Here is the Code

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var email2 = context.Session["Emailadd"];
    context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(email2));
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get { return false; }
}
```

But the value returned from this page is NULL. What Am i Missing ??? Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why do you serialize email as JSON? If you want to return JSON why do you set response content type to `text/plain`?

Comment: That Was Just Copy Paste Of the Code which i was using for other handlers where i was getting return Type Of IEnumerable<>.